# Unable to install a dependency, tried installing an npm package with --legacy-peer-deps

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-install, connect-mongo

[Compatibility error with installed dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz5ix.png)

[Tried changing the version of the dependency to 6.1.0 in package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tyRq.png)

[After changing the version, I tried re-installing but the problem still persists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8tzP.png)

[After trying --legacy-peer-deps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAb3K.png)

[error from "npm install command"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVBhF.png)

I tried to install (connect-mongo) package "npm install connect-mongo" which led me to this error.

Then I tried changing the version of the dependency to 6.1.0 in package.json file

But still got the error message

then I had to try and do "npm install connect-mongo --legacy-peer-deps"

but the error still persists

Would I be able to use the package after doing "npm install connect-mongo --legacy-peer-deps"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this might help (or if you tried it) but when I face a similar situation I delete the node modules folder and try the installation again using the --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: I'll try that as a last resort, thank you